# Making a web request with SSL Certificate and SOAP on C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, web-services, soap

I am facing an issue while making a request to an external web service from a C# code with SSL certificate authentication. Currently I am getting error code 500 Internal Server Error from that web service as response.

C# code to make request object and call it:

public class ERCOTWebRequest
{

```
    string action = @"https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS?MarketInfo";

    public bool GetReports()
    {
        try
        {
            // WebRequestHelper.
            var request = CreateSOAPWebRequest();


            XmlDocument SOAPReqBody = new XmlDocument();
            //SOAP Body Request  
            string nodalXml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\test\source\repos\WebRequestHelper\ERCOTWebServiceHelper\XMLFile1.xml");



            SOAPReqBody.LoadXml(nodalXml);

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                SOAPReqBody.Save(stream);
            }
            
            //Geting response from request  
            using (WebResponse Serviceres = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(Serviceres.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    //reading stream  
                    var ServiceResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    //writting stream result on console  
                    Console.WriteLine(ServiceResult);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }

    public HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
    {
        string host = @"https://testmisapi.ercot.com/2007-08/Nodal/eEDS/EWS/";
        string certName = @"C:\Users\Test\Downloads\ERCOT_TEST_CA\TestAPI123.pfx";
        string password = @"password";
        
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        X509Certificate2Collection certificates = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        certificates.Import(certName, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host);
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.ClientCertificates = certificates;
        req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
        req.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
        //HTTP method    
        req.Method = "POST";
        return req;
    }
}
```

Currently I am getting an error(Error 500: Internal Server error) while trying to make SOAP request. Someone please help.